# Laravel Eloquent select only data which is not used as foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've got a license table with this scheme:

```
license_id | licenseKey | update_from
```

This table contains some license keys, which can be updates from other licenses.

`update_from` points to an id of a data, if it is null, the license is NOT an update.

How can I only select the licenses, which aren't used as an update? (whose id is NOT used as update_from)

Example:
I've got this table:

```
license_id | licenseKey  | update_from
1          | XX-XX-XX-XX | null
2          | YY-YY-YY-YY | null
3          | ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ | 1
```

From this data, i want to select the data with id 2 and 3 (3 is an update from 1, so I don't want to select 1, 'cause it's already updated)

Edit:
Problem solved with this code:

```
$subquery = License::select('update_from')->whereNotNull('update_from')->toSql();
$query->whereRaw('license_id not in (' . $subquery . ')');
```

I've already got a query `$query`, just updated it with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to filter our the entries where `updated_from` is not null:

```php
$subquery = DB::table('license')
              ->select('update_from')
              ->whereNotNull('update_from')
              ->toSql();

$licenses = DB::table('license')
              ->whereRaw('license_id not in (' . $subquery . ')')
              ->get();
```

To have the same thing with Eloquent:

```php
$subquery = License::select('update_from')->whereNotNull('update_from')->toSql();
$licenses = License::whereRaw('license_id not in (' . $subquery . ')')->get();
```

For a better understanding of what's going on, here's the query being generated by the Query Builder:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `license`
WHERE license_id NOT IN
    ( SELECT `update_from`
     FROM `license`
     WHERE `update_from` IS NOT NULL)
```

Also here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/640d8/1) that runs this query using the schema and sample data you posted.

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution is more "Eloquent-ish" and doesn't deal with SQL.

```
$licenses = License::whereNotIn('id',function($query){
    $query->from((new License)->getTable())->whereNotNull('update_from')->lists('update_from');
})->get();
```

Comment: Very nice approach. Although it won't work in its current form, because you're missing a condition on the subquery. It should look like this: `$query->from((new App\License)->getTable())->whereNotNull('update_from')->lists('update_from');`.

Comment: Cool, then let's update it for future references... thanks.